# ClickOnce download timeout issue

Tags: download, timeout, clickonce

Hope you might have come across the ClickOnce download timeout issue.
The download just stops at a point (where it tries to download a .deploy file of >2MB)
and throws the timeout error.

Any ideas on resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your network speed, your network connections, and talk to whoever is hosting your application. You can run fiddler and see the files coming across. This is not a ClickOnce problem, it is a network issue.